# Properly discontinuous action and topological manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $G$ be a finite group that acts properly discontinuous in a topological space $E$ and let be $B=E/G$.

How can I show that $E$ is a $n$-dimensional topological manifold if and only if $B$ is a $n$-dimensional topological manifold?

I know I need to use that $E \rightarrow B$ is a covering map. But I have problems to show they are Hausdorffs and second-countable spaces.